# Call custom URL according to form field in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url

I am trying to accomplish something seemingly simple.

I would like to create a WordPress form field in which a user can enter an alphanumerical text. So far so good.

The challenge: This entry should be appended to the URL which is called when clicking the Submit button.

For example:

> User enters: *LookBlueElephants*
>   On submit the user gets directed to *http://www.example.com/LookBlueElephants*

I am using the DIVI Builder and see that there is an option to enter the Redirect-URL in the form. Yet I do not know how to get it to be dynamic, based on the user input.

Thank you for your assistance. :-)

Comment: If you want the user input you can use `$_GET` or `$_POST` php vars. If your input field name is "name" then you are redirecting to  `your_url/$_POST["name"]`. For more info you can check php manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Thank you. That is true, but these variables are only available after the user pressed the Submit button. I basically want the user to end up on http://www.example.com/LookBlueElephants after clicking on the Submit button. 
  Would I have to create a target-page for the button and process the variables there somehow? If so, how? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alright. After much tinkering, here the solution I took.

Created a form with [Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com) and added [Redirection for Contact Form 7](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/) Plugin. With a plugin that allows inserting PHP code (for example [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/)) I added a simple redirect:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/' . $_GET['your-variable']);
exit;
```

Just make sure that under Redirect Settings (in the Contact Form 7 settings) the box "Pass all the fields from the form as URL query parameters" is ticked.

Then create a new page where you insert the above code snippet (how that is done may depend on which plugin you use). Now enter the URL to that page into the Contact Form settings (Redirect Settings) and you're done.

The form will send the content of the form to the new page, the new page will take the GET variables and redirect to wherever you want.

Hope this will be of use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for your input.
After finding your solution, I tried a workaround using Elementor Pro Form that has after submit actions.

- Give an ID to your Field on the advanced tab.
- Copy the shortcode generated, looks like this : [field id="example"]
- On the actions after submit option, select Redirect.
- Redirect menu should appear, Choose redirect to shortcode and paste the shortcode we generated
- On the advanced options of the shortcode redirection, put a before value (your domain).
  Save changes.

It then generates a link after submit like : wwww.yourdomain.com/whatever-you-wrote-on-field